# error while building APK in android studio for flutter project

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, android-studio

Building with sound null safety

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not delete old C:\Users\Best Computers\StudioProjects\shoes\build\app\reports\lint-results-release-fatal.html

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 49s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          172.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add checkReleaseBuilds to false in your build.gradle. It will be look like.

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Or can you try File > Invalidate Caches/Restart